# Import data. COPY & INSERT in Cassandra

Tags: postgresql, cassandra

I am trying to find out how different relational and NoSQL databases work in order to understand the performance behavior of this or that database. 
So yesterday I created a database with PostgreSQL [CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074757/csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table/37076626#37076626).

The same example: Movielens (http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/). We've got movies and ratings. Movies have multiple genres. I splitted those out into a separate table since it's a 1:many relationship. There's a many:many relationship as well, users to movies. I need to be able to query this table multiple ways.

Now I want to create the same databsase with Cassandra. I model my tables to be optimized to answer specific queries

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    movie_id int primary key,
    title text,
    avg_rating decimal,
    total_ratings int,
    genres set<text>
);

# shows all movies for specific genre
CREATE TABLE genre_to_movies (
    genre text,
    movie_id int,
    name text,
    primary key (genre, movie_id)
);

# show the number of movies of specific genre
CREATE TABLE movies_per_genre (
    genre text primary key,
    movies int
);

# shows all ratings for specific movie
CREATE TABLE ratings_by_movie (
    movie_id int,
    user_id int,
    rating decimal,
    ts int,
    primary key(movie_id, user_id)
);

# show all ratings of specific user
CREATE TABLE ratings_by_user (
    user_id int,
    movie_id int,
    rating decimal,
    ts int,
    primary key(user_id, movie_id)
);
```

I have 2 csv files:
**movies.csv**: movie_id; movie_name; genre_name

```
1;Toy Story (1995);Animation|Children's|Comedy
```

**ratings.csv**: user_id; movie_id; rating, timestamp

```
1;1193;5;978300760
```

What ist the best way to import data into my tables?
For example, how can I import data to genres set from movies.csv? How can I split the string "Animation|Children's|Comedy"?
If I do it manually:

```
INSERT INTO movies(movie_id,..., genre) VALUES ('Toy Story (1995)', ...,['Animation','Children's','Comedy'])
```

but how can I import this data for all movies?

**Can you please show the best strategy for COPY & INSERT commands using this example/database?**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a small importer program to do this.  For instance, if you're using Python + Pandas, read_csv will do the import, then for each movie you can split the genres to insert a set of text fields.

I wrote an utility to learn Cassandra called "cassandra dataset manager", or CDM.  The first importer for CDM is the movielens dataset.  Reading through the source might help you.  I suggest looking at install.py and movielens.helpers: https://github.com/rustyrazorblade/movielens-small

Answer (score 0):

You can use [COPY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) command to import data from your csv file

```
 COPY movies(movie_id, title, genres) FROM 'movie.csv' WITH DELIMITER =';' AND HEADER = TRUE;
```